# How does ehcache write-behind handle: shutdown, eviction b/c cache is full, eviction b/c TTL expired?

Tags: ehcache

We're switching to using EhCache's write-behind feature but I can't tell from the documentation how these three cases are handled.

If I've put something in the cache via putWithWriter() and my cacheWriter hasn't yet been called, what happens if the element is evicted (due to space or due to ttl)?  Is my cacheWriter automatically called with this item prior to eviction?

Similar question at program exit time....if I call getCacheManager.shutdown() are all of the unwrite items sent to my cache writer?